# Get value from xml response in Python

Tags: python, powershell

I need to rewrite scripts from PowerShell to python and I'm new to python.
How can I get value from XML response in python e.g

I have a response in XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Channels resultCount="1" xmlns="urn:xmlsample:1.0">
  <Channel id="01">
    <Events resultCount="1">
      <Event id="123456789abcdefghij"/>
    </Events>
  </Channel>
</Channels>
```

I need to get only value from Event id in response

```
123456789abcdefghij
```

In PowerShell, I added

```xml
[xml]$xml = $req
$xml.Channels.Channel.Events.Event.Id
```

Is there is an equivalent in python?
I only find how to get value from the xml file but I need from response.

For now, I have

```py
import requests

requestIP = 'http://192.168.0.12/channel' # enter IP

def getEventsToRecord():
    body = '<SubQueryOptions xmlns="urn:xmlsample:1.0"><QueryOption path="Events">/filter/AvailabilityStart>=now()&amp;AvailabilityEnd&lt;now(P1D)</QueryOption></SubQueryOptions>'
    r = requests.request("PUT", f'{requestIP}/Channels', data = body)
    print(r.text)
```

Comment: Can you use `BeautifulSoup` for parsing the XML?

Comment: All examples are good, but what if I have more than 1 Event?
I tried to do that but response that I received is always 1 event

Comment: If there are multiple events, then you would loop over them. There are thousands of examples on the internet of looping over a collection in Python. BeautifulSoup's documentation gives examples for retrieving a list of elements. Do some homework; this is not a tutorial site, but a QA site. It is your responsibility to write well researched, complete and verifiable questions. You never once mentioned this in your question. Both answers listed are complete, given the question asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have [pip](https://pypi.org/project/pip/) installed, you can do this very easily with two external packages.

`pip install lxml` and `pip install bs4`

`lxml` is the xml parser that will be used by [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) (bs4). After those two are installed, the code is nearly identical to your PowerShell code:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
req = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Channels resultCount="1" xmlns="urn:xmlsample:1.0">
 <Channel id="01">
    <Events resultCount="1">
      <Event id="123456789abcdefghij"/>
    </Events>
  </Channel>
</Channels>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(req, "xml")
soup.Channels.Channel.Events.Event["id"]
'123456789abcdefghij'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here (no need to install any external software)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import re

data = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Channels resultCount="1" xmlns="urn:xmlsample:1.0">
  <Channel id="01">
    <Events resultCount="1">
      <Event id="123456789abcdefghij"/>
    </Events>
  </Channel>
</Channels>
    '''

data = re.sub(' xmlns="[^"]+"', '', data, count=1)
root = ET.fromstring(data)
event_id = root.find('.//Event').attrib['id']
print(event_id)
```

output

```
123456789abcdefghij
```